# Why was there 3 seconds local delay to send out the query from local by using jdbcTemplate.query()?

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, jdbctemplate, delayed-execution

Our Java code has a delay issue to send out the SQL query request to remote SQL Server DB by using jdbcTemplate.query().
resultMap = (HashMap)jdbcTemplate.query(query,new ResultSetExtractor(){}...

Here is what we found so far.

We has logs output to our log file. Also, we used Wireshark to trace the network activities on the same host which our code app running.

Then, we noticed that our log displayed **@08:10:45**, the code is about to call jdbcTemplate.query().

Log: "Query logged just before sending to DB– From our logs"

**Line 578471: 2020-06-24 08:10:45,530 INFO  Util.dao.CallMeNowDaoImpl [taskExecutor-269708] -  get Ewt In Min QUERY: select QueueID, EWT from PROD_VHT_RB.dbo.QueueStatistics where QueueID IN ('UK_e2M_Account_Chat_VQ','UK_e2M_Account_Email_VQ','UK_e2M_Account_Phone_VQ')**

But, based on the Wireshark trace file, we saw 3 seconds later, **@08:10:48**, the query was just sent to DB. So, here we have a seconds local delay issue.

Wireshark Trace: "Time when query is sent DB - From Wireshark"

**80628   2020-06-24 08:10:48.117453             10.129.67.12               10.232.160.128 TDS        388               93.115169000   0.000053000               SQL batch
select QueueID, EWT from PROD_VHT_RB.dbo.QueueStatistics where QueueID IN ('UK_e2M_Account_Chat_VQ','UK_e2M_Account_Email_VQ','UK_e2M_Account_Phone_VQ')**

One fact I need to share first is - our code is running as a service which is called by multiple clients. There are about 20K requests in one hour from our clients sent to that service to call the mentioned query method in different threads. Most of the requests didn't have above delay but only about 0.02% percent requests have that delay issue. I am not sure if there is a bottle-neck on the jdbcTemplate.query() method itself which might be not able to process that much requests quickly enough or not at some time points. Could that be a potential root cause?

Can you help me how to investigate why I got 3 seconds local delay here further? What could be the root cause and potential solution of the delay issue?

Here is the code snippet how the code calls the jdbcTemplate.query() method in our service code.

```
public EwtPojo getEwtInMin(String queue, EwtPojo ewtPojo) throws DAOException{
         long startTime = logMethodBegin("getEwtInMin");   
         HashMap<String,Long> resultMap = new HashMap<String,Long>();
          HashMap<String,String> resultErrorMap = new HashMap<String,String>();
         try{                
                String query = vhtEwtQuery+"'"+AppUtil.getQueueString(queue)+"')";
                logger.info(" get VHT Ewt In Min QUERY: " +query );
                JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = jdbcVhtTemplate; 
                resultMap = (HashMap)jdbcTemplate.query(query,
                              new ResultSetExtractor() {
                                    public Object extractData(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException {
                                          Map map = new HashMap();
                                          while (rs.next()) {
                                                 String queueId = rs.getString("QueueID");
                                                 String ewt = rs.getString("EWT");
                                                 Long ewtInMin = 0L;
                                                 try {
                                                        ewtInMin = calculateEWTInMins(ewt);
                                                        logger.info("VHT - For Queue - {}, EWT Additional min mentioned in config file - {}, EWT from DB - {}, EWT in minutes {}", queueId, vhtEWtAdditionalMin, ewt, ewtInMin);
                                                 } catch (Exception e) {
                                                 resultErrorMap.put("vqName",ewt+" - "+e.getMessage());
                                                        //throw new SQLException("Exception occurred while calculating EWT to min from given String");
                                                 }
                                                 map.put(queueId, ewtInMin);
                                          }
                                          return map;
                                    }
                });
                logger.info("Time taken to get results for query - {}, is - {} sec",query, (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime)/1000);
              if(resultMap.isEmpty()){
                resultErrorMap.put(queue,"No Results found for this queue/queues in VHT DB");
                }
          if(addToVhtEwt) {
                persistEwtOrError(resultMap, resultErrorMap);
          }
          ewtPojo = addEwtAndErrorMap(ewtPojo, resultMap, resultErrorMap);
          ewtPojo = addToErrorMap(queue, ewtPojo);
          return ewtPojo;            
         }catch(Exception exception){
          logger.error("Exception occurred while getting EWT in min.",exception);
         throw new DAOException("Exception occurred while getting EWT in min["+exception.getMessage()+"]",exception);
   }finally {
         logMethodExit("getEwtInMin",startTime);
   }
   }
```

Comment: If this only occurs under load, perhaps it's waiting for an available connection from the pool.

Comment: If it's intermittent it could also be the garbage collector doing a mark and release cycle.

Comment: @DanGuzman, thank you! Do you mean jdbc pool? So, where can I increase the available connection numbers from the pool?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning, thanks! So, how can I improve the performance? Thank you!

Comment: Garbage-collected languages like Java and .NET suffer from stutters and pauses whenever the garbage collector does a mark and release cycle. It's exacerbated in programs that frequently allocate and dispose small allocations and the delay increases on systems where the program has access to large amounts of memory (so the mark and release passes take longer to execute). You'll never entirely beat it but you need to design your software to minimize allocations and disposals by keeping pools of reusable objects. That's not a trivial task we can help you with on StackOverflow.